# Multiple Optional Interfaces modeling (OOP)

Tags: class, oop, interface, uml

I came across a problem in modeling a system.

Imagine the following scenario:

- Person is a class
- A Student is a Person
- A Programmer is a Person
- A Football fan is a Person

Obviously Person would be the super class of those three, but I want to be able to have a Person, who is a Student *and* a Programmer without having to create a seperate class implementing those as interfaces for every single combination. What's the common way to model something like this?

Thanks,

Anton

Comment: Could you detail what is different between Person, Student, Programmer, Football fan ? For example,  if hey have the same set of attributes and methods, one class with an attribute type is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person might have multiple roles that might change from time to time.
If you handle Person and Role as two separate concepts and by having a 1:n relation between the two concepts you would avoid the superclass idea.

So saying "a student is a person" can also be stated as "a person may have the role student for a certain time period".

[image: Person versus roles]

Answer (score 2):

You should not confuse identity-bearing kinds with the roles they play. Instead, you should use an instance of a Person with references to instances representing the roles the Person plays. That way, a Person (or even a Robot) can play the role of Football Fan and Student at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You don't. A `StudentProgrammer` is probably just a `Student` but definitely not a `Programmer` since the latter is doing it for a living. A `StudentProgrammer` is a new class. You might derive it from `Student`, eventually. From my POV it's always a good idea to correlate with real world objects. Without you end up with strange constructs like multiple inheritance - which is just unnatural. An amphibian vehicle does not inherit from car and ship. It's a class of its own.